# Javascript, turn off multiple devices

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have rewritten my code so that I now have three lights which I turn off one by one.
Is there a way to place all three of them in a variable to just run the turn off command once?

```
// Turn off a bunch of lights

// Specify ID for a specific lamp
let KitchentableRight = await Homey.devices.getDevice({id: 'ef6bae9c-ec57-46ff-9011-905f90d16589'});
let KitchentableMiddle = await Homey.devices.getDevice({id: 'e29ab963-5139-4fdb-b4ec-ec25c103a62a'});
let KitchentableLeft = await Homey.devices.getDevice({id: '8b102bc6-00dd-4305-b111-f67a53ffd9d9'});

// Turn off tha lights based on their ID:s
KitchentableRight.setCapabilityValue('onoff', false);
KitchentableMiddle.setCapabilityValue('onoff', false);
KitchentableLeft.setCapabilityValue('onoff', false);

return true
```

Comment: I have no idea about Homey, but the return false inside of your forEach does not do what you expect.

Comment: I try to write it using javascript library. https://apps.athom.com/app/com.athom.homeyscript

Comment: I don't think you are using `forEach` good. `devices` will be each entry of your array `a` and `device` will be the index. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: I was trying using that page you linked me too trying to create my sript, but apparently I did it all wrong.

Comment: Updated my scipt above. It turn on lights but not just them in the list. Above script toggles but I would like to check if light is on and if true turn of. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

to make the loop runs for each device it should be:

```
 devices.forEach(device => {
       if(device.name) return false;
        console.log(device.name);
        device.setCapabilityValue('onoff', !device.state.onoff);
    })
```

if a is array of device's name, you can check if the device in a by: `a.indexOf(device.name) != -1`

Comment: I created a to put the different variables (lamps) I wanted to turn of. Not sure how to ise your code to loop through the array to turn of all lamps.The code give error "Error: devices.foreach is not a function"